# Dynamically Creating form elements

Tags: angular

Scenario: I have two forms (1. form1, 2.form2). Form1 has a text box, and the user is allowed to write anything inside it. If the user types something like given below in the text box.

> The Variable {Var0} is greater than Variable {Var1}

I need to extract `Var0` and `Var1` and create two new dropdowns in another form (ie Form2), one named `Var0` and other `Var1`

```
this.form.get('message').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  this.variables = [];
  if (val) {
    var rex = /[^{\}]+(?=})/g;
    var matches = val.match(rex);
    if (matches) {
      for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        this.variables.push(new VariableDropDown({
          key: matches[i],
          label: matches[i],
          options: ['Good','Bad','Ugly'],
          order: 0
        }));
      }
    }
  }
  this.formGroup = this.vcs.toFormGroup(this.variables);
})
```

Here I'm subscribing to the `message` text box and every time when the user types, I'm clearing the dynamic form element (ie `this.variables`) and then I'm checking the value of entered message and extracting the values inside `{ }` using a regex and pushing to the dynamic form element `this.variables`. So far it's working fine. But the problem is, I type `The Variable {Var0} is greater than Variable {Var1}` and select the below two options and Again If I type one letter extra, the previously selected options goes off. How to solve it?

To know more about the issue, please go through this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4d1k1y)

Answer (score 0):

This hppens because valueChanges emits new event in the stream and then you're resetting your variables prop. It depends on the requirements, that you have. You can play with valueChanges stream, to allow this re-rendering only in some specific cases. I would use

```
valueChanges.pipe(
// you can filter stream based on your requirements, 
// e.g debounceTime +  distinctUntilChanged
).subscribe(
//your current logic here
);
```